# CV2 can't read Webcam on MacBook Pro

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV can't read my webcam even though I granted permission and the Mac is telling me that Python uses my webcam. It is clearly capturing something and I don't get an error however the preview window will not open:

[image: example]

When I open an already downloaded picture or mp4 it works without any problems.
I use Python 3.7 and opencv-python-4.5.1.48 on MacOS Big Sur.

EDIT: The exact same code works in BootCamp without problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an unknown reason, if you installed openCV with `pip install opencv-python`, it won't work with macOS's privacy policy.

You should instead use the brew package

```sh
brew install opencv

# Brew will probably need to overwrite previous openCV installations
brew link --overwrite opencv
```

As soon as you create the VideoCapture object, your webcam indicator should light up

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```